# Pass value from query 1 to query 2

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a query join 2 table as below:

```
SELECT * FROM Staff s INNER JOIN Account a on s.AccNo = a.AccNo WHERE a.Status = 'Active'
```

The result as shown:

```
 AccNo | Name | ID
 ------------------ 
   1   | Alex | S01
   2   | John | S02
```

After I get the staff ID,I write second query to find out the max sale as below:

```
SELECT s.ProductID,Max(s.Amount) from Sales s WHERE StaffID = 'S01' GROUP BY s.ProductID
```

The max sale for Staff 'S01' as below:

```
ProductID  | Amount
------------------
   Cloth   | 2000
```

How to I combine these 2 queries and become result as below?  Thanks

```
 AccNo | Name | ID | Amount
 -------------------------- 
   1   | Alex | S01 | 2000
   2   | John | S02 | 5000
```

Comment: Please check join in sql [link]http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp[/link]

Comment: Wait. Is `StaffId` a field in `Sales` or `Transaction`?

Comment: Sorry typo,I was edited my question. StaffID is in Account.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a subquery and join it:

```
SELECT a.AccNo, b.Name, b.ID, c.maximum 
FROM transaction as a 
INNER JOIN Account as b 
ON a.AccNo = b.AccNo
LEFT JOIN (SELECT StaffID, Max(Amount) as maximum FROM Sales GROUP BY StaffID) as c 
ON c.StaffID = b.ID
WHERE b.Status = 'Active'
```

See the [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2a91/7/0) (I've tried to guess the schema)

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is join to sales on the staffId then group.

```
SELECT a.AccNo,a.Name,a.ID,Max(s.Amount) 
FROM Transaction t 
INNER JOIN Account a on t.AccNo = a.AccNo 
INNER JOIN Sales s on s.staffId = a.ID
WHERE a.Status = 'Active'
GROUP BY a.AccNo,a.Name,a.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Select Account.*, Max(Sales.amount) from Sales 
JOIN Account ON Sales.StaffID = Account.ID 
where Account.status = 'Active'
group by Sales.ProductID, Account.AccNo, Account.Name, Account.ID
```

Honestly, I don't understand why do you use Transascation table in your queries, because you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

Just do a join and retrieve the max amount associated with each staff

SELECT t.AccNo , t.Name, t.ID, s.ProductID, Max(s.Amount) FROM Transaction t

INNER JOIN Account a ON t.AccNo = a.AccNo

INNER JOIN Sales s ON s.StaffID = a.ID

WHERE a.Status = 'Active';

Thanks